# How does a class name work as a data type in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm a newbie to Scala, and I know this question is little naive, but I'm really confused how the class name is used as a data type. I've tried to google, I got results for ADT, type variance, etc, but I didn't get a concrete understanding as in how does this work as a data type.

for example I've a class Customer, and class Bank. Class customer has the details of customer. Can someone explain how Bank Class takes the "Customer" as a data type? and is there a specific term which defines this?

```
class Customer(f:String,l:String,e:String) {
  val first = f
  val last = l
  val email = e
}

class Bank(n:String, cs:Set[Customer]){
  val customer:Set[Customer] = cs
  val name:String = n
}
```

Comment: This is  basically an Object Oriented Programming concept wherein you express relationship between objects. Please refer https://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/composition-and-aggregation.html

Comment: Basically every time you are declaring a **class/trait/object** you are defining a new **type** too. You may find [this](https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html) interesting. - Also, a bit unrelated but, you do not need to  create _vals_ with the same values as your constructor arguments. If you want them to be public just put the `val` on the constructor.

Comment: ... or make these `case class`es to be even more concise (also gives you lots of helper methods like copy-constructors, proper toString and equals etc).

Comment: The `Bank` class "takes" the `Customer` data type in the same way it "takes" `String` for `name`. When you define your own types, they can be used just like the built-in types.

Comment: Is it the `Set[Customer]` part that confuses you? `val customer: Set[Customer]` means that `customer` is a field that stores  `Set` instances, and `Set` it turn is a "generic" class that is further parameterized by the type of elements in it, here `Customer`s.  If you wanted to have a field with just a single customer, you could have a plain `val favouriteCustomer: Customer`. There are many such "collection" types, such as `List[Customer]` or `Option[Customer]` or `Map[String, Customer]` and all of them take "type parameters" to specify what kind of element can be put in them.